# How to update view with no model from controller in Sencha Touch?

Tags: view, sencha-touch

For some views I use just a controller (no model). How do I update the view after I've made some changes to it's components. Say, I can use the *setValue* method on a TextField to change the value of the field, but there is no equivalent *setLabel* method. Do I have to call some method to update the view after changing the *label* property of a TextField component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just alter the HTML of the label element.

```
var tf = <some text field>
tf.labelEl.setHTML('<span>NEW LABEL</span>');
```

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to set the label from the API they expose.  But if they did, I imagine that it would look like this:

```
function setLabel(text){
  this.labelEl.setHTML('<span>' + text + '</span>');
}
```